# How to optimize a search over ldap?

Tags: algorithm, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have a only-read user in the ldap of my organization that use openldap implementation, I don't know exactly the structure of the tree but I know that there are many organizational units below objects bogota, medellin, palmira, (which in turn are below of organization `xxx.edu.co`). I'm interested in search `uid` of people using another attribute named `employeeNumber`, in each `people` organizational unit below  of organizations in second level (bogota, medellin, palmira). I can achive this through:

```
ldapsearch -h secret.xxx.edu.co -D 'uid=myUser,ou=Institucional,o=bogota,o=xxx.edu.co' -w myPass -x -b 'ou=People,o=bogota,o=xxx.edu.co' '(&(employeeNumber=123485))'
```

The problem with this is the efficency, given that my organization counts with more of 40000 users the search is very very slow, If I search using the uid the search is very fast, I guess that the tree is exactly ordered by the 'uid' or something like that. The point is that precisely the uids are my objective, additional I know a approximate form of the uid of the person that I search, for example I know that if I'm searching for the uid for Pepito Pérez with employeeNumber=12345, this must be start with a 'p'.

How I can achive a better performance in this problem?

I think that something like filter the tree by a regexp in the indexed uid attribute and after search for the employeeNumber in this subset could have good performance. I need a approach that not require admin privileges in ldap.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an `equality` index added to the `employeeNumber` attribute. This would make your above search perform as well as the uid search.

If you want to do partial `uid` matching efficiently you will require a `substring` index on the `uid` attribute.

Aside, your filter `(&(employeeNumber=123485))` can simply be expressed as `(employeeNumber=123485)`. There is no need for the `and (&)` as there is only one clause.

If you had the appropriate indexes you could perform a search with a filter like this...

`(&(employeeNumber=123485)(uid=p*))`

and that would get you exactly what you want.

Comment: Effectively a equality index added to the employeeNumber is the ideal solution to my problem, if I hadn't a user with only read privileges.

Comment: so, you have no control over what is indexed at all? Since that is the case and you only have 40,000 entries, i would grab the keys for all of them and make a local database that just maps keys. I would keep just the employeeNumber and the directories unique id; these are unlikely to change. keep it up to date by looking for newly create entries periodically.  When you need to search for a user by employeeNumber, do your local translation and search by unique id instead.  If not found do a subsequent search for the user by employeeNumber but control with createtime since your last sync.